# Instanciate FBLoginView class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-3.0

I try to implement **Facebook SDK** in an IOS Swift project, but I can't include the SDK.
Moreover, I don't know how to translate this Objective-c snippet to Swift :-

```
[FBLoginView class];
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way I found is to add a new "Objective-C File" into your project.

It should ask you "*Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?*" Choose **Yes**.

Two files will be added to your project, the Objective-C file and "**(project name)-Bridging-Header.h**"

Delete the empty Objective-C file you added and open **(project name)-Bridging-Header.h**

Add your import for the Facebook SDK into the file (using the Objective-C style import), example:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Save the header file and you can now access Facebook SDK in your swift code. **You do not** need to add "import FacebookSDK" into your swift files. Example:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var fbl: FBLoginView = FBLoginView()
    // etc...
```

Comment: I don't want to add a new "Objective-C File" but a Framework. I follow  [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) and drop the ".framework" file to my project. I can create my view and add the class "FbLoginView", but I can't instantiate a FBLoginView class.

Comment: Right, the only reason you need to add an Objective-C file is to create the Bridging-Header file (I believe this also sets a flag in your project somewhere). The Objective-C file is not needed, it's just a quick way to create the Bridging header file and set the flag in your project. Then adding the import to the Bridging header allows you to access FBLoginView in your project. You still need to have the Facebook SDK framework already in your project.

Comment: Work like a charm ! Thank you for your help ! I'll try to find an easier way to create the bridge file.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do with the class?

In swift you can reference the class with `.self` like so:

```
FBLoginView.self
```

Comment: According to [Facebook SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0), I need to load FBLoginView class. But it seems that the framework isn't properly included.

Comment: "FacebookSDK.framework" appears in my "Linked frameworks and libraries" but it still doesn't work

Comment: What exactly does `FBLoginView.self` do?

Comment: @Half_Duplex it gives you a reference to the Class itself - It is equivalent to the objC code in the question `[FBLoginView class]`

Answer (score 0):

Believe with the latest updates from Facebook, the imports for the Header File are:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h> 
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```